# Bacula on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, backup

I setup a new Ubuntu desktop system, I called BACULA, to install Bacula  to backup 3 other systems (TRISTRAM: Ubuntu, NANCY: Windows/10, MILLY: Windows/10).

Everything seems to be OK, but I have a few problems:

1. While the Tray Monitor on BACULA can access the Storage Daemon, it cannot access the File Daemon.
2. The Director Daemon cannot access the File Daemon either. I even tried with removing the firewalls all Windows (.
3. The Console on the clients cannot access the Director. If I look for the open ports (nmap bacula), I see that ports 9102 and 9103 are open but NOT 9101!

here is the Console object in bacula-dir:

```
Director {                            # define myself
  Name = Bacula-dir
  DIRport = 9101                # where we listen for UA connections
  QueryFile = "/etc/bacula/scripts/query.sql"
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/lib/bacula"
  PidDirectory = "/var/run/bacula"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 1
  Password = "Console password"
  Messages = Daemon
  DirAddress = localhost
}

.....

#
# Restricted console used by tray-monitor to get the status of the director
#
Console {
  Name = bacula-mon
  Password = "password for monitor"
  CommandACL = status, .status
}
```

the full bacula-fd:

```
# Default  Bacula File Daemon Configuration file
#
#  For Bacula release 9.4.2 (04 February 2019) -- ubuntu 20.04
#
# There is not much to change here except perhaps the
# File daemon Name to
#
#
# Copyright (C) 2000-2015 Kern Sibbald
# License: BSD 2-Clause; see file LICENSE-FOSS

# List Directors who are permitted to contact this File daemon
#
Director {
  Name = Bacula-dir
  Password = "Console password"
}
#
# Restricted Director, used by tray-monitor to get the
#   status of the file daemon
#
Director {
  Name = Bacula-mon
  Password = "password for monitor"
  Monitor = yes
}
#
# "Global" File daemon configuration specifications
#
FileDaemon {                          # this is me
  Name = Bacula-fd
  FDport = 9102                  # where we listen for the director
  WorkingDirectory = /var/lib/bacula
  Plugin Directory = /usr/lib/bacula
  Pid Directory = /run/bacula
}
#
# Send all messages except skipped files back to Director
#
Messages {
  Name = Standard
  director = Bacula-dir = all, !skipped, !restored
}
```

and the bacula-tray-monitor-dir:

```
#
# Bacula Tray Monitor Configuration File
#
# Copyright (C) 2000-2017 Kern Sibbald
# License: BSD 2-Clause; see file LICENSE-FOSS
#
Monitor {
  Name = bacula-mon
  RefreshInterval = 30 seconds
}
#
Client {
  Name = bacula-fd
  Address = localhost
  Port = 9102
  Password = "password for monitor"          # password for FileDaemon
  Connect Timeout = 30
  Monitor = yes
}
#
Storage {
  Name = bacula-sd
  Address = localhost
  Port = 9103
  Password = "password for monitor"          # password for StorageDaemon
}
#
Director {
  Name = bacula-dir
  Address = localhost
  Port = 9101
  Password = "password for monitor"          # password for the Directors   
}
```

Comment: Hello. I see you have a question about BACULA. There is no mention of any issue in your question with the Ubuntu OS only this application. This app has its own support. I suggest you may want to contact them.

Comment: There are two issues: 1) the authentication with bacula-fd fails and 2) the director port (9101) is not open for access to the clients.